# Power BI Error: We cannot convert the value "I" to type Record

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI, and I have this error when I try to "Remove Empty".
This initial column was a List and then I expanded it with "Expand To new Rows" option .
The error message is:
"We cannot convert the value "I" to type Record. "
Details: 
Value=I 
Type=[Type]

Thank for your help.

[This image summarizes the steps I follow until I have the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIY82.jpg)

Comment: Please show a sample of your data, and how to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please share the screenshot if possible?

Comment: What is the datatype of that "I" value that the engine can't convert to "Record"? 
Do you even have "Empty" values on your column "Specialization"? What are you trying to accomplish?